# Windows SYSTEM PID 4 listing on port 31337 (eleet)

Tags: windows, malware

On my Windows 7 box,

I have the following ports opened by the system process..

```
Process PID     PROTO   LOCAL           REMOTE          State

System  4   TCP 0.0.0.0 445 0.0.0.0 0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCP 0.0.0.0 2869    0.0.0.0 0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCP 0.0.0.0 5357    0.0.0.0 0   LISTENING                                       
System  4   TCP 0.0.0.0 31337   0.0.0.0 0   LISTENING
```

I cant find what the trojan is that causing that, I have done all the usual BO searches and the fact that PID 4 is concerning. I tried ProcessExplorer and still no help any ideas? All antiviruses that I have tried Symantec, MalwareBytes and MS Security Essentials return nothing.

Doing a telnet to that port

```
telnet localhost 31337
Escape character is '^]'.
?
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 20:50:26 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Where can I start looking ?

Turns out this was a services called "VirtualRouter" that create a HTTP service. Uninstalling it fixed the problem. MSConfig was the key tool in disabling services. Also starting with "V" in my binary search method to narrow down the service. was the last services I tried! Phew glad its not a trojan!

Comment: glad you figured it out. from your telnet, its clearly an http daemon based on its response. good troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to try:

- Use MSConfig to turn off all non-MS services and 3rd party start-up programs.  If it's not listening anymore, turn them on one at a time until you find the culprit.
- Run `netstat -ab` from an elevated command prompt to get different information about the ports.  If it turns out to be a "Svchost" listening on that port, start disabling services until you figure out which service is the culprit.

Comment: Its not svchost its "SYSTEM" and so I cannot get more information about it.. with the netstat command

Comment: The MSConfig suggestion is great one, turning off all the services seems to have got rid of it, I am doing a binary search of figuring out which service it is..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a services called "VirtualRouter" that create a HTTP service. Uninstalling it fixed the problem. MSConfig was the key tool in disabling services. Also starting with "V" in my binary search method to narrow down the service. was the last services I tried! Phew glad its not a trojan!